# How to create a deb-package of plugin with qml components (without C++)

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qmake, qtquick2

In a standard case people have an opportunity to create qml-plugins with C++. It is very easy, however whole internet have nothing about creating qml-components. I mean not really "creating" a component but making it able to package and deploy, something like "qmake; make; make install" algorithm which will look for qmldir file and add to "install" a copy action of qml-components described there.

In case of C++-plugin I am able to create a makefile which will install anything in the right places (shared library and qmldir). I need this for qml files but for qml files we have no any Makefile.

Back to reality, I've made my own qml-control. I want to package it into a deb file and upload it to my ppa, after that I wanna use it as dependency in another projects. What steps should I follow in order to create what I've said above here?

`Control.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
    width:20
    height:20
}
```

`qmldir`

```
module my.controls
Control 1.0 Control.qml
plugin mycontrols
```

Comment: I do not follow. You can install anything with qmake rules just as well as with raw make rules. What problem exactly are you facing? You may want to check out the [harmattan components](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/harmattan-qt-components/source/7d9bf82a089a60429e279d26dc305d34386b7295:) that I used to work on back then. That exactly did what you want.

Comment: So here is no any default algorithm for that? I mean I need to create a whole deb-package by myself with proper install script which will copy files I need, etc..? I am not worrying about it just asking is here any algorithm or people do this manually.

Comment: You never have any algorithm. You always write the build system for yourself for good, especially with raw makefiles. Why don't you even use  qmake? I would be quite worried if something "intelligent" decides ruling me out where to install stuff.

Comment: I agree with you, but `qmake` always know where to install because of `qtchooser` I think. So I need to find out default `qml_import_path` and install files there. It looks I got everything I need, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just follow the same install procedure except that you install the components into a path where they will be recognized when they are imported. See [the import path list in the engine](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#importPathList).

> By default, the list contains the directory of the application executable, paths specified in the QML2_IMPORT_PATH environment variable, and the builtin Qml2ImportsPath from QLibraryInfo.

Answer (score 0):

However your solution is solution too and I might be using it soon I still want to answer my own question.

Suppose we have own qml-components and `qmldir` file. In this case we need to do everything manually, but we can create `.pro` file which always know (by qmake) where to install your stuff. So, `pro` file must look like this:

```
TEMPLATE = lib

uri = my.controls

# Input
OTHER_FILES = qmldir \
    Control.qml

qmldir.files = $$OTHER_FILES
unix {
    installPath = $$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/$$replace(uri, \\., /)
    qmldir.path = $$installPath
    INSTALLS += qmldir
}
```